# No output running yui-compressor from Ant

Tags: ant, yui-compressor

I'm going to minify my js files by yuicomressor via ant, I wrote this:

```
<property name="concat-js-file-name" value="main.concat.js"/>
<property name="concat-js-file-path" value="${temp-folder}/js/${concat-js-file-name}"/>
<property name="yui-jar-path" value="lib/yuicompressor-2.4.7.jar"/>
<target name="minification" depends="concatation">
    <echo>---Minification is started</echo>
    <java jar="${yui-jar-path}" fork="true">

        <arg value="${concat-js-file-path}"/>
        <arg value="-o  minified.js"/>
    </java>
    <echo>---Minification is finished successfully...</echo>
</target>
```

The problem is the output file is not generated!
Any idea?

Answer (score 0):

You should set `<java ... failonerror="true"/>` and increase the noiselevel to see what's going on, means start your ant build with `ant -f yourbuild.xml -debug`

Answer (score 0):

Actually, after some tries I found a solution:
I used `<arg line="-o outputfile inputfile"/>` instead, and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest using `<arg value="...">` instead of `<arg line="...">`. `<arg value="...">` ensures that each command line argument has quotes around it, if necessary.

In the case of yui-compressor, the `"-o"` and `"<file>"` arguments should each go in their own `<arg value="...">` elements:

```
<java jar="${yui-jar-path}" fork="true">
    <arg value="-o"/>
    <arg value="minified.js"/>
    <arg value="${concat-js-file-path}"/>
</java>
```